# Work arounds for HTTP sites, microphone access

Tags: javascript, php, http, https, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use HTML5's Speech Recognition, and I got it to work, but there's just one problem. On http sites, it always prompts the user repeatedly for right to access the microphone every time the user finishes speaking. You can see how that can be a problem. However that doesn't happen on https sites.

The problem is that my site is a http site and not a https site. So my question is, are there any ways around this? Other than purchasing a htpps site of course. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, and there is a good reason for that.

If it was possible, it will mean that anyone on the network can listen to the microphone of that user :

- User A contact website B over http
- Website B ask permission for microphone
- User A grants it
- later, User C, on the same network than use A, change any http request to add a custom JS forcing a request to website B
- The browser of user A will make the request to website B
- User C intercept that request to capture user A microphone

So your only solution is to get a certificate (you can have one for free from https://www.startssl.com/ )

(And if anyone found another way, it will be a security bug!)

Comment: Ah. What a pain. Thanks.